# Print env vars in javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I print env vars, or any var, in src generates by javascript_include_tag?

I'm trying do something like this:

```
javascript_include_tag '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY']&sensor=true'
```

But, don't work of course!

Comment: "don't work" is not a good problem description. Try to explain the issue and / or post the errors encountered

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to javascript include tag and it's interpreting `ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY']` as simple string.you should write in ruby code like `#{ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY']}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the quotes in the code you posted:

`ENV["GOOGLE_API_KEY']`

(Notice the last quotation mark.)

You also need to use string interpolation. Try this:

```
javascript_include_tag "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] }&sensor=true"
```